# Cant boot after clean install

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

i recently built my first computer, here are the specs:

Intel i5-7600
Motherboard Asus Prime Z270-k
8gb DDR4 Crucial ballistix
120gb SSD PNY
PSU EVGA 600B

I installed everything correctly, i also got a clean install of windows from a usb using the Windows media tool to my SSD.

Till that, everything worked correctly, but each time i turn on the pc, it doesnt go directly to the windows user login. I have to enter BIOS, use the BOOT mode and select the SSD so it loads windows.

Note:
I already have my SSD on the N° 1 SATA PORT.

I installed it on legacy

Solution:

Go to your BIOS, Advanced info, and disable CSM
Reboot from the usb Flash drive, erase all partitions on your SSD, create a New one and install it there. Now it will automatically boot.

Comment: Which Windows version? And have you installed in UEFI or Legacy mode?

Comment: Windows 10 Home 64 bits.

I dont know which one since all ive done was follow windows steps for the installation

Comment: Whenever you need to add or correct information please [edit] your question. That said, Windows 10 can be installed in either mode and that's determined by *how* you booted the installer. Please include that information as well and, if you don't know what I'm talking about, reinstall Windows after changing the mode to UEFI only which is the preferred mode for any Windows 8 or newer.

Comment: THanks for the answer. Ive checked on Msinfo32 and it says Legacy. I booted from the Usb flash drive.

Comment: But it boots from USB?, it would have booted from the SSD at least once during the install. Does the option ROM list the SSD as the 1st choice ? Or after USB, Optical ?

Comment: I installed it from the usb Flash drive, then i unplugged it and started booting from the ssd but manually.

When i enter the BIOS, i only have the SSD on the list so yes its first.

i dont have an optical drive.

I only have a laptop apart from this pc.

Comment: Again, for better results, disable Legacy/CSM support (="UEFI only") and reinstall. This way it boots and installs in UEFI mode *and* then it'll boot Windows directly. Do NOT use Legacy/CSM unless the OS is so old that has no support for UEFI, not the case with Windows 10, obliviously.

Comment: Thanks for all. I just reinstalled on UEFI mode and now it boots directly.